# Sum of the series $\sum_i |i|^\alpha$

Tags: summation

I am looking for the sum to the following finite series:

$ \sum_{i=0}^N |i|^\alpha $

where $0<\alpha<1$.

Thanks.

Comment: actually $\alpha>0$ ...

Comment: are you assuming $\alpha$ is rational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is any "nice" way to write the answer,

Whenever you want to know how to solve such sums, let $S_n = \sum_{i = 0}^n i^\alpha$

Then $$S_{n+1} - S_n = (n+1)^\alpha$$
is the equation you want to solve.

If you type it into [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), you will get an expression using Hurwitz and Riemann Zeta functions. Neither can be calculated by hand easily.

[$$S_{n+1} - S_n = (n+1)^\alpha$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=u%28n%2b1%29%20-%20u%28n%29%20=%20%28n%2b1%29%5Ea)